# U.S. Income Tax Calculator based on filing status

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simply U.S. Income Tax calculator in python using functions. No matter what I put as filing status I always get the numbers for "single". I am trying to have it run the correct function based on what is input as the filing status by the user.

I have have created functions for each filing status to get tax rate as well as to get the flat tax minimum as outlined by the tax code.

I know that the end result isn't going to be exactly correct but I am doing this as an exercise in functions and creating a more complex program

Any help is appreciated.

```
income = float(input("How much do you make? :"))
filing_status = input("What is your filing status? :").capitalize()

# Determine Static Deduction
def single_static_calc():
            if income <= 10275:
                return 0
            elif income <= 41775:
                return 1027.59
            elif income <= 89075:
                return 4807.50
            elif income <= 170050:
                return 15213.50
            elif income <= 215950:
                return 34647.50
            elif income <= 539900:
                return 49335.50
            else:
                return 162718

def ms_static_calc():
            if income <= 10275:
                return 0
            elif income <= 41775:
                return 1027.59
            elif income <= 89075:
                return 4807.50
            elif income <= 170050:
                return 15213.50
            elif income <= 215950:
                return 34647.50
            elif income <= 323925:
                return 49335.50
            else:
                return 86127

def hh_static_calc():
            if income <= 14650:
                return 0
            elif income <= 55900:
                return 1465
            elif income <= 89050:
                return 6415
            elif income <= 170050:
                return 13708
            elif income <= 215950:
                return 33148.50
            elif income <= 539900:
                return 47836.50
            else:
                return 162218.50

def mj_static_calc():
            if income <= 20550:
                return 0
            elif income <= 83550:
                return 2055
            elif income <= 178150:
                return 9615
            elif income <= 340100:
                return 30427
            elif income <= 431900:
                return 69295
            elif income <= 647850:
                return 98671
            else:
                return 174253.50

def static_criteria():
    if filing_status == "Single":
        return single_static_calc()
    elif filing_status == "Married Separate":
        return ms_static_calc()
    elif filing_status == "Head of Household":
        return hh_static_calc()
    elif filing_status == "Married Jointly":
        return mj_static_calc()
    else:
         return single_static_calc()

static = static_criteria()
print("Static Amount is:", static)

# Determine your tax rate
def single_rate_calc():
            if income <= 10275:
                return .10
            elif income <= 41775:
                return .12
            elif income <= 89075:
                return .22
            elif income <= 170050:
                return .24
            elif income <= 215950:
                return .32
            elif income <= 539900:
                return .35
            else:
                return .37

def ms_rate_calc():
            if income <= 10275:
                return .10
            elif income <= 41775:
                return .12
            elif income <= 89075:
                return .22
            elif income <= 170050:
                return .24
            elif income <= 215950:
                return .32
            elif income <= 323925:
                return .35
            else:
                return .37

def hh_rate_calc():
            if income <= 14650:
                return .10
            elif income <= 55900:
                return .12
            elif income <= 89050:
                return .22
            elif income <= 170050:
                return .24
            elif income <= 215950:
                return .32
            elif income <= 539900:
                return .35
            else:
                return .37

def mj_rate_calc():
            if income <= 20550:
                return .10
            elif income <= 83550:
                return .12
            elif income <= 178150:
                return .22
            elif income <= 340100:
                return .24
            elif income <= 431900:
                return .32
            elif income <= 647850:
                return .35
            else:
                return .37

def rate_criteria():
    if filing_status == "Single":
        return single_rate_calc()
    elif filing_status == "Married Separate":
        return ms_rate_calc()
    elif filing_status == "Head of Household":
        return hh_rate_calc()
    elif filing_status == "Married Jointly":
        return mj_rate_calc()
    else:
        return single_rate_calc()

rate = rate_criteria()
print("rate is:", rate)

#Taxes
after_static = income - static
rate_tax = after_static * rate
tax_owed = rate_tax + static

income_after_tax = income - tax_owed

print("With the income of $", income, "you will pay $",tax_owed,"in tax.")
print("You will have $",income_after_tax,"Left")
```

Comment: `.capitalize()` only capitalizes the first letter of the string, not each word, so your if/elif conditions fail when your user input string contains more than one word (which they all do, except for `Single`). Instead consider `.title()`.

Comment: Did you check what [`capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) is doing? `"married separate".capitalize()` gives `'Married separate'`

Comment: Alot easier to just `.lower()` all inputs and work with all-lowercase strings...

Comment: Also please take a look at how to create a [mre]. Most the code here is not at all relevant for identifying the problem

Comment: Don't use a blanket `else` to return the same thing that one of your earlier conditions returns. Have your error-check condition return something like `9999999` or `"invalid entry"` so that you can catch and debug more easily. Much like having a blank `except: pass` clause in a `try:except`, you're masking the issue

Comment: I have changed my .captialize() to .lower()

Also changed my blanked else statements to "Error in X function"

I am looking at the linked artical for "minimal reproduciable example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`capitalize()` only capitalizes the first letter of the string, So `filling_status == Single` is working and the `else` block is working, both of which are returning `single_statuc_calc()`

> Python String capitalize() function is used to convert only the first character to the uppercase letter, rest all characters are lowercase. [refer](https://www.askpython.com/python/string/python-string-capitalize-function)

change

```
filing_status = input("What is your filing status? :").capitalize()
```

to

```
filing_status = input("What is your filing status? :").lower()
```

also, change

```
Single -> single
Married -> married 
Head of Household -> head of household
Married Jointly -> married jointly
```

**Change 1**

```
income = float(input("How much do you make? :"))
filing_status = input("What is your filing status? :").lower()
```

**Change 2**

```
def static_criteria():
    if filing_status == "single":
        return single_static_calc()
    elif filing_status == "married separate":
        return ms_static_calc()
    elif filing_status == "head of household":
        return hh_static_calc()
    elif filing_status == "married jointly":
        return mj_static_calc()
    else:
         return single_static_calc()
```

**Change 3**

```
def rate_criteria():
    if filing_status == "single":
        return single_rate_calc()
    elif filing_status == "married separate":
        return ms_rate_calc()
    elif filing_status == "head of household":
        return hh_rate_calc()
    elif filing_status == "married jointly":
        return mj_rate_calc()
    else:
        return single_rate_calc()
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my oversights. I have done the above changes as well as implemented some breakpoints and error handling to help narrow it down. I really appreciate your detailed answer